# java SimpleDateFormat pattern different with argument

Tags: java, date

SimpleDateFormat pattern is "yyyyMM", and the arg is yyyy-MM, but there are no exception and a wrong result. why?   thx~~

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
System.out.println(format.format(format.parse("2011-07")));
```

the result is 201105

Comment: a bit strange but it looks like it graps year correct and then month as -7 so 12-7=5

Comment: @Blem: correct. If you look at the source code there's even special logic to recognize minus signs in arabic text (where they're placed *after* the number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setLenient(false)`; it will then throw the exception you expect.

See the [setLenient() docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

The input to `parse` is wrong, try

System.out.println(format.format(format.parse("201107")));

With 2011-07 it interprets the month as negative 7 months which results 201005 (12-7=5).