# Error parsing String to Date in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date

Yes, another Java Date post :)

My problem:

simple standard code, used for test if an inserted date is in the requested form (dd/MM/yyyy):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try {

   sdf.parse(strDate); 

} catch(ParseException e) {

   // err

}
```

> strDate = "10-12-2012" ----> sysout = err (ok)
>
> strDate = "2012-11-10" ----> sysout = err (ok)
>
> strDate = "15/10/2011" ----> sysout = parse (ok)

*the problem:*

> strDate = "2012/12/15" ----> sysout = this date that i expect an error
>   result parsed like "Tue Jun 03 00:00:00 CET 21"

Who knows???

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? I don't quite understand the question. Is it failing parsing?

Comment: http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/techtip-use-of-setlenient-method-on-simpledateformat/

Comment: @TheCat.. It is parsing the string correctly, that should not be parsed.

Comment: @SérgioMichels, enter an answer with `setLenient()` and the OP can accept it as answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [java SimpleDateFormat pattern different with argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804703/java-simpledateformat-pattern-different-with-argument)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just set [**setLenient**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to **false**.

FROM API :

[setLenient method:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With
>   lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs
>   that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing,
>   inputs must match this object's format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try {
  sdf.setLenient(false);
  System.out.println(sdf.parse("2012/12/15")); 
} catch(ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Great, many tnx for clearing ideas, it's in my evernote now :)